# bash scripting if condition error

Tags: bash

This is my first bash script to sync my contents to the server. I want to pass the folder to be synced as a parameter. However, it does not work as expected.

This is my script (saved as sync.sh):

```
echo "STARTING SYNCING... PLEASE WAIT!"
var="$1" ;
echo "parameter given is $var"

if [ "$var"=="main" ] || [ "$var"=="all" ] ; then
    echo "*** syncing  main ***" ;
    rsync -Paz /home/chris/project/main/ user@remote_host:webapps/project/main/ 
fi

if [ "$var"=="system" ] || [ "$var"=="all" ] ; then
    echo "*** syncing  system ***" ;
    rsync -Paz /home/chris/project/system/ user@remote_host:webapps/project/system/ 
fi

if [ "$var"=="templates" ] || [ "$var"=="all" ] ; then
    echo "*** syncing  templates ***" ;
    rsync -Paz /home/chris/project/templates/ user@remote_host:webapps/project/templates/ 
fi
```

And this my output:

```
chris@mint-desktop ~/project/ $ sh ./sync.sh templates
STARTING SYNCING... PLEASE WAIT!
parameter given is templates
*** syncing  main ***
^Z
[5]+  Stopped                 sh ./sync.sh templates
```

Although I gave "templates" as an argument, it ignores it. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments below, this is my suggested corrected script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "STARTING SYNCING... PLEASE WAIT!"
var="$1" ;
echo "parameter given is $var"

if [ "$var" == "main" -o "$var" == "all" ] ; then
    echo "*** syncing  main ***" ;
    rsync -Paz /home/chris/project/main/ user@remote_host:webapps/project/main/ 
fi

if [ "$var" == "system" -o "$var" == "all" ] ; then
    echo "*** syncing  system ***" ;
    rsync -Paz /home/chris/project/system/ user@remote_host:webapps/project/system/ 
fi

if [ "$var" == "templates" -o "$var" == "all" ] ; then
    echo "*** syncing  templates ***" ;
    rsync -Paz /home/chris/project/templates/ user@remote_host:webapps/project/templates/ 
fi
```

Comment: `[ "$var" == "main" || "$var" == "all" ]` should be changed to `[ "$var" == "main" -o "$var" == "all" ]`

Comment: or it can be changed to use double brackets i.e. `[[ "$var" == "main" || "$var" == "all" ]]`

Comment: You are correct, I didn't test my script (I was at the wrong computer). I'll make sure to test before I post in the future. I have corrected my solution.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that too. But I still get a similar error as the one I get when I apply @dogbane's suggestion: `STARTING SYNCING... PLEASE WAIT!
parameter given is templates
./sync.sh: 5: [: templates: unexpected operator
./sync.sh: 10: [: templates: unexpected operator
./sync.sh: 15: [: templates: unexpected operator
./sync.sh: 20: [: templates: unexpected operator
`

Comment: Are you really running bash? Did you put `#!/bin/bash` at the top of the script or run it as `bash sync.sh`?

Comment: yes. `#!/bin/bash` is at the top of the script. However I run it as `sh ./sync.sh` (as I mentioned in my question). I tried `bash ./sync.sh` as you suggested and it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You need a space on either side of the `==` operator. Change it to:

```
if [ "$var" == "main" ] || [ "$var" == "all" ] ; then
    echo "*** syncing  main ***" ;
    rsync -Paz /home/chris/project/main/ user@remote_host:webapps/project/main/ 
fi
```

Comment: Thanks. I used to have spaces around `==` but I was getting this: `STARTING SYNCING... PLEASE WAIT!
parameter given is templates
./sync.sh: 5: [: templates: unexpected operator
./sync.sh: 5: [: templates: unexpected operator
./sync.sh: 10: [: templates: unexpected operator
./sync.sh: 10: [: templates: unexpected operator
./sync.sh: 15: [: templates: unexpected operator
./sync.sh: 15: [: templates: unexpected operator
./sync.sh: 20: [: templates: unexpected operator
./sync.sh: 20: [: templates: unexpected operator`